# Own reference structure to DOT language

Tags: c#, graph, graphviz, decision-tree, dot

I creating decision tree in C# where nodes are objects and branches are references and I wounder If I can use some tool to change this structure into DOT language graph to use it in graphviz?
If there any better way to build this graph?

Comment: Please add your classes definitions to question. What is node object and how it refer other nodes?

Comment: now i have single object just to build this tree, nothing special. every single object have list of edges to other nodes. Its simple list of references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your node looks like this

```
public class Node
{
    public Node(string name)
    {
        ChildNodes = new List<Node>();
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Node> ChildNodes { get; set; }
}
```

you can create `dot` file with this code:

```
private static void PrintInDotFormat(Node root)
{
    // 1. Create graph
    var nodes = new HashSet<Node>();
    var openList = new Queue<Node>();
    var references = new List<KeyValuePair<Node, Node>>();

    openList.Enqueue(root);
    while (openList.Count > 0)
    {
        var current = openList.Dequeue();
        nodes.Add(current);
        foreach (var child in current.ChildNodes)
        {
            references.Add(new KeyValuePair<Node, Node>(current, child));

            if (nodes.Contains(child))
                continue;
            openList.Enqueue(child);
        }
    }

    // 2. Print it to console
    Console.WriteLine("digraph DecisionTree {");
    foreach (var node in nodes)
        Console.Write($"{node.Name};");

    Console.WriteLine();

    foreach (var pair in references)
        Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key.Name}->{pair.Value.Name};");

    Console.WriteLine("}");
}
```

Usage:

```
var root = new Node("root");
root.ChildNodes.Add(new Node("a"));
root.ChildNodes.Add(new Node("b"));
root.ChildNodes.Add(new Node("c"));

PrintInDotFormat(root);
```

This code will print grap in `dot` file format:

```
digraph DecisionTree {
root;a;b;c;
root->a;
root->b;
root->c;
}
```

After processing by `dot.exe`:
[image]

Comment: i will try this solution